# Pointers in Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm new to `C++`, so my code is not optimal, but at the moment I just want it to work.
I have to write a `function` that compares every 2 elements (1. and 2., 2. and 3. etc.) of `linked list` and deletes the first of these two elements if it's smaller than the next one. At the end I have to display the list adter editing. I found some examples of what I'm trying to do, but they make me confused and I have no idea how to adjust them to my case.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct elements {
    int value;
    elements * next;
};

void f (elements * & start){
    if (start == NULL || start -> next == NULL) {  
        return;
    }
    elements * p = start, * prevvalue = NULL, * previous = NULL, * del, * before = NULL, * after = NULL;
    int first = start -> value;
    int second = 0;
    for (; p != NULL; p = p -> next){ 
        cout << p -> value << endl;
        second = p -> value;
        if (first < (p -> value)) {
            before = prevvalue; 
            del = p;
            previous = p;
            p -> next = after -> next;
            after -> next = p;
            delete del;
        }
        first = second;
        previous = prevvalue;
    }
    if (previous == NULL) start = start -> next;
    else prevvalue -> next = start -> next;
}

int main (){
    elements * start = NULL, * last = NULL, * input;
    int count;
    cout << "How many elmenets would you like to input? ";
    cin >> count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        cout << "Please input " << i + 1 << ". element: ";
        elements * input = new elements;
        cin >> input -> value;
        input -> next = NULL;
        if (last != NULL) {
            last -> next = input;
            last = input;
        }
        else start = last = input;
    }   
    f (start);
    elements * p = start;
    while (p != NULL) {
        cout << p -> value << endl;
        p = p -> next;
    }
    input = start;
    while (start != NULL){
        elements * temp = start;
        start = start -> next;
        delete temp;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There's something totally wrong with pointers, so it's not working.
Can someone please edit my code and throw out everything that's unnecessary?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can I suggest you spend a little time looking at the formatting and getting the indentation nice?

Comment: Is this a homework? If not, you're not trying to do C++, but C.

Comment: So if input is  1,2,3,4,5 -> result is 5, and if input in 5,2,3,4,1 -> 541?

Comment: Yes, it's a homework and yes, results are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some cleanup something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct elements {
    int value;
    elements* next;
};

elements* funkcija(elements *start) {
    if (start == NULL || start->next == NULL) {
        return start;
    }

    elements *list = start;
    elements *current = start;

    elements *previous = nullptr;

    while(current) {
        elements* next = current->next;
        if (!next) {
            break;
        }

        if (current->value < next->value) {
            if (previous) {
                delete current;
                previous->next = next;
            }
            else {
                list = next;
                delete current;
            }
            current = nullptr;

        }
        else {
            previous = current;
        }

        current = next;
    }

    return list;
}

int main() {
    elements *start = NULL, *last = NULL;
    int count;
    cout << "How many elmenets would you like to input? ";
    cin >> count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cout << "Please input " << i + 1 << ". element: ";
        elements* input = new elements;
        cin >> input->value;
        input->next = NULL;
        if (last != NULL) {
            last->next = input;
            last = input;
        }
        else {
            start = last = input;
        }
    }
    start = funkcija(start);
    elements * p = start;

    while (p != NULL) {
        cout << p->value << endl;
        p = p->next;
    }

    while (start != NULL) {
        elements * temp = start;
        start = start->next;
        delete temp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot! :)